# Basic pattern recognition in binary (pixelated) image

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, algorithm, image-processing

Here is a cropped example (about `11x9` pixels) of the kind of images (which ultimately are actually all of size `28x28`, but stored in memory flattened as a `784`-components array) I will be trying to apply the algorithm on:

[image: sample image]

Basically, I want to be able to recognize when this shape appears (red lines are used to put emphasis on the separation of the pixels, while the surrounding black border is used to better outline the image against the white background of StackOverflow):

[image: sample shape]

The orientation of it doesn't matter: it must be detected in any of its possible representations (rotations and symmetries) along the horizontal and vertical axis (so, for example, a 45° rotation shouldn't be considered, nor a diagonal symmetry: only consider 90°, 180°, and 270° rotations, for example).

There are two solutions to be found on that image that I first presented, though only one needs to be found (ignore the gray blurr surrounding the white region):

[image: first example highlighted]

Take this other sample (which also demonstrates that the white figures inside the images aren't always fully surrounded by black pixels):

[image: example 2]

The function should **return True** because the shape is present:

[image: highlighting the shape]

Now, there is obviously a simple solution to this:

Use a variable such as `pattern = [[1,0,0,0],[1,1,1,1]]`, produce its variations, and then slide all of the variations along the image until an exact match is found at which point the whole thing just stops and returns `True`.

This would, however, in the worst case scenario, take up to `8*(28-2)*(28-4)*(2*4)` which is approximately **40000 operations** for a single image, which seem a bit overkill (if I did my quick calculations right).

I'm guessing one way of making this naive approach better would be to first of all scan the image until I find the very first white pixel, and then start looking for the pattern 4 rows and 4 columns earlier than that point, but even that doesn't seem good enough.

Any ideas? Maybe this kind of function has already been implemented in some library? **I'm looking for an implementation or an algorithm that beats my naive approach.**

*As a side note, while kind of a hack, I'm guessing this is the kind of problem that can be offloaded to the GPU but I do not have much experience with that. **While it wouldn't be what I'm looking for primarily**, if you provide an answer, feel free to add a GPU-related note.*

---

**EDIT**:

I ended up making an implementation of the accepted answer. You can see my code in [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/payne911/2a7474d113159ad6c632618bd620a861).

Comment: When you manage to figure out a viable solution to your problem I'd really like to have a look at the source if you're willing to share it.

Comment: I sure will. Would you mind sharing what kind of applications you have in mind for such a solution? Or do you want the code only because you are being curious? :)

Comment: @Jake12342134 there you go: https://gist.github.com/payne911/2a7474d113159ad6c632618bd620a861#file-image_integral-py

Comment: Hello, thank you for the code! I'm excited to take a look. I asked solely out of curiosity!

Comment: @Jake12342134 no worries! I was using this code to detect whether or not a 28x28 picture represented a convex figure without any learning algorithm. I ended up with a >99% accuracy, which isn't bad.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have too many operations, think how to do less of them.

For this problem I'd use image integrals.

If you convolve a summing kernel over the image (this is a very fast operation in fft domain with just `conv2`,`imfilter`), you know that only locations where the integral is equal to 5 (in your case) are possible pattern matching places. Checking those (even for your 4 rotations) should be computationally very fast. There can not be more than 50 locations in your example image that fit this pattern.

My python is not too fluent, but this is the proof of concept for your first image in MATLAB, I am sure that translating this code should not be a problem.

```matlab
% get the same image you have (imgur upscaled it and made it RGB)
I=rgb2gray(imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/l3u4A.png'));
I=imresize(I,[9 11]);
I=double(I>50);

% Integral filter definition (with your desired size)
h=ones(3,4);

% horizontal and vertical filter (because your filter is  not square)
Ifiltv=imfilter(I,h);
Ifilth=imfilter(I,h');
% find the locations where integral is exactly the value you want
[xh,yh]=find(Ifilth==5);
[xv,yv]=find(Ifiltv==5);

% this is just plotting, for completeness
figure()
imshow(I,[]);
hold on
plot(yh,xh,'r.');
plot(yv,xv,'r.');
```

This results in 14 locations to check. My standard computer takes 230ns on average on computing both image integrals, which I would call *fast*.

[image]

Also GPU computing is not a hack :D. Its the way to go with a big bunch of problems because of the enormous computing power they have. E.g. convolutions in GPUs are incredibly fast.

Comment: Would you mind explaining what you mean by "convolve a summing kernel over the image" ? My understanding is that you are basically sliding the pattern over the image as a mask and calculating the sum of the logical AND on each region, only keeping in memory the points where it was equal to 5 (since there are 5 white pixels in the pattern). I'm guessing you're doing so with every possible variation of the pattern so this operation would be repeated 8 times (because of symmetries/rotations). *Note:* I'm having trouble understanding how to use those red dots: none would allow the pattern to match

Comment: @payne "sliding the pattern over the image as a mask" -> convolution. Then I selected the only locations (red dots) that sum to 5. Only those can match your pattern, no other location can. Im not saying they do, I am saying they are the only ones that have 5 pixels white. as your pattern. I have not given you the location of the pattern, I have given you a very reduced list of possible locations of the pattern. Then just check it using whatever you where doing before.

Comment: Also, about your GPU note, maybe I should precise my thinking: my guess is that a GPU could reduce the time required to compute the solution, but it wouldn't actually change the algorithmic complexity of the solution proposed (the same amount of operations will be required). My goal is to try to find a nicer approach then the naive one, algorithmically speaking.

Comment: @payne no, summing all the values of an array is `O(n)` on CPU and `O(log(n))` in GPU. But you need to read a couple of books to understand this better, a comment here won't cut it. GPUs have *simultaneous* operations, so if you can do a thing at the same time as another one, the complexity is reduced, as its related to time.

Comment: @payne please take some time to read about some of the concepts I introduced, so you understand the answer better. Read about what "convolution" is in image processing and why it is fast. Also read about what an "image integral" is, as its the core of the answer. I am not using your pattern at no point, just doing a trick to reduce significantly the locations you need to check for the pattern.

Comment: I now realize I was wrong thinking you were sliding my pattern over the image. Your solution is quite elegant: off to reading I go! (One last question: what does "fft domain" mean? "Fast Fourier Transformation"?)

Comment: @payne yes, convolutions are made in Fourier domain, using FFT (as you said ;). Its a neat trick to instead of writing some loops, converting the "sliding" in a multiplication. Just some random maths. The important thing here is that its very fast.

Comment: I ended up implementing your solution: it worked perfectly. I really enjoyed reading on this technique: thank you for sharing! (I have shared a Gist containing my code as a reply to a commenter on the OP.)

Answer (score 5):

The operation you are implementing is an operator in Mathematical Morphology called [hit and miss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hit-or-miss_transform).

It can be implemented very efficiently as a composition of two erosions. If the shape you’re detecting can be decomposed into a few simple geometrical shapes (especially rectangles are quick to compute) then the operator can be even more efficient.

You’ll find very efficient erosions in most image processing libraries, for example try OpenCV. OpenCV also has a hit and miss operator, [here is a tutorial for how to use it](https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/db/d06/tutorial_hitOrMiss.html).

---

As an example for what output to expect, I generated a simple test image (left), applied a hit and miss operator with a template that matches at exactly one place in the image (middle), and again with a template that does not match anywhere (right):

[image: Image showing the three images as described above]

I did this in MATLAB, not Python, because I have it open and it's easiest for me to use. This is the code:

```matlab
se = [1,1,1,1      % Defines the template
      0,0,0,1];
img = [0,0,0,0,0,0 % Defines the test image
       0,1,1,1,1,0
       0,0,0,0,1,0
       0,0,0,0,0,0
       0,0,0,0,0,0
       0,0,0,0,0,0];
img = dip_image(img,'bin');

res1 = hitmiss(img,se);
res2 = hitmiss(img,rot90(se,2));

% Quick-and-dirty display
h = dipshow([img,res1,res2]);
diptruesize(h,'tight',3000)
hold on
plot([5.5,5.5],[-0.5,5.5],'r-')
plot([11.5,11.5],[-0.5,5.5],'r-')
```

The code above uses the hit and miss operator as I implemented in [DIPimage](http://diplib.org). This same implementation is available in [DIPlib](http://diplib.org)'s Python bindings as `dip.HitAndMiss()` (install with `pip install diplib`):

```
import diplib as dip
# ...
res = dip.HitAndMiss(img, se)
```

Comment: I knew there had to be something quite similar to my naive approach already implemented in OpenCV: thank you for the keyword and link! What is the algorithm's complexity, however ? And is it already implemented so as to offload to the GPU (I'm quite new to OpenCV in general) ?

Comment: @payne: Complexity is O(n), but that is true for most image processing algorithms, you need to visit each pixel. Your example shape is separable into 3 lines (one black, the miss kernel, two white, together the hit kernel). An erosion with a line can be computed in time independent of its length, just 3 comparisons per image pixel. You’d do this 3 times, then compare the outputs, maybe 11 or 12 operations per pixel. — I’m not sure if OpenCV implements it this way. But OpenCV does have GPU implementations of a lot of its algorithms.

Comment: @Ander: Morpholog has a lot of very interesting operators, it’s still a very active, if small, community. Also most people think that morphology is only applicable to binary images...

Comment: @CrisLuengo I've edited the OP with the actual proper shape. I thought I was making it clearer with a `3x4` example, but it seems like both answers didn't exactly catch that I actually only wanted the relevant `2x4` portion of the pattern. If it wasn't for that smaller size, certain edge-cases wouldn't get detected. Just thought I'd let you know.

Comment: @CrisLuengo regarding the complexity, my understanding is that I would run the algo 8 times (one for each orientation of my pattern) over the whole image, whereas with Ander's method, I would run only once through the image to obtain the possible matches, and then I would run 8 times the verification on each possibility: it sounds like a better approach. Thoughts? Did I miss-understand the workings of your Hit-Or-Miss suggestion? *(By the way, I tried editing your suggestion to change `hit and miss` to `hit or miss` but it wasn't enough characters for it to be accepted)*

Comment: @payne: Some sources refer to it as “hit or miss”, but I think it’s a misnomer, because you want to hit some pixels AND miss some other pixels. Plenty of other sources use the same terminology that I use, [for example](https://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/hitmiss.htm).

Comment: @payne: Regarding the pattern: I did assume you had a 2x4 matrix there, but it doesn’t really matter, you can use any pattern in either Ander’s or my approach.

Comment: @payne: Ander’s method is quite efficient especially considering you need to do several orientations. The integral image you compute only once, and the final counts you compute twice (2x4 and 4x2). Then it depends on how many points match the count, how much work you end up doing. But it is a clever approach. I wanted to add this answer not because it is more efficient, but because this is a standard operator and there exist efficient implementations ready to use. It’s always best to do that over rolling your own, until you’ve demonstrated it’s a bottleneck in your processing.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I wanted to see how well your answer would work, but it seems like I'm having trouble using the tool you've suggested. [Here is a Gist](https://gist.github.com/payne911/37c218d163c33b37d9a2abd4023c9060) with Python code that creates the patterns I want to use and takes a fake image to test them all. I'm having trouble understanding if the results are correct or not, and if they are, I'm unsure as of how to use such information. [Here is a screenshot](https://snag.gy/R0T5V7.jpg) of the results: the first image is my "fake image" used to find matches, with the results below.

Comment: @payne: I have no idea why you get the results you're getting there. I have edited the answer with results from an implementation that I know is correct (because I wrote it), using the test image and template as in your Gist. As you can see, the expected output is a single pixel set in the middle of each hit. Because the template is even in size, what is considered the "middle" of the template is up for debate... :)

Comment: @CrisLuengo Maybe what I'm not understanding is the process to create the "merged kernel". The one I was using has `-1` instead of `0`s like the one you have used. I've just tried that change and it doesn't seem to have solved my problem ([image of the results](https://snag.gy/61wiEV.jpg)). Maybe the Python implementation uses the arguments in a different manner?