# What's a good way of pattern recognition with existing template?

Tags: algorithm, pattern-recognition

Suppose that I have a 6 by 6 matrix/image A with a pattern in it, i.e.

```
0 0 0 0 0 0
1 0 0 0 0 0
0 1 0 0 0 0
0 0 1 0 0 0
0 0 0 1 0 0
0 0 0 0 1 0
```

And suppose that I have a template of Pattern that I want to recognize,
i.e. a 5 by 5 matrix B

```
0 0 1 0 0
0 0 1 0 0
0 0 1 0 0
0 0 1 0 0
0 0 1 0 0
```

Suppose we can apply matrix algebra, element wise calculation.
What's the quickest and efficient way to recognize the existence of pattern indicated by matrix B in matrix A?(Notice the "angle" of rotation in A was generate treated as unknown.)

Comment: How do you characterize a pattern? Do the 0s matter at all, or can they always be ignored? Is the only possible rotation a multiple of 45 degrees? Are mirror images considered as matches? How large can the haystack matrix (matrix A) be? Does it wrap in any sense?

Comment: @tucuxi In this case, I used 1 to represent pattern in matrix B, 0 did not matter. The pattern is thus a line segment of length 5. A was just a simple demonstration, the pattern in B can under go transitional changes and rotation changes. Flip is in general permitted but should return a negative value, i.e. (if 1 is yes and 0 is no, a flip should be -1) Right now I'm want to make sure the algorithms can say yes or no, it doesn't need to indicate where the pattern is at or in which rotation it's been placed. However, if the algorithm can point out the exact position and rotation, it's preferred

Comment: @tucuxi First I want to be able to recognize the pattern. It's not necessarily to point out where the pattern is or at which rotation, because the efficiency and speed(amount of calculation that was needed) was my main focus.

Comment: @user9976437: how do yo characterize a rotation? what is a 45deg rotation of a checkerboard pattern? Are rotations of arbitrary angles allowed, even say 23deg? Does the pattern consist only of zeros and ones?

Comment: [This question, and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53440762/basic-pattern-recognition-in-binary-pixelated-image), seem relevant.